# Programmatically add customer login through soap api

Tags: magento-1.9, soap

I want to add customer login outside magento.and also set session. I am using magento with third party application connected with soap api. Using soap api is any solution to authenticate customer login as well as set session.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android magento - customer login(authentication) using SOAP API](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72901/android-magento-customer-loginauthentication-using-soap-api)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's duplicated.

Magento SOAP API has no method to authenticate customers.

What you can do is, get the customer info and then check the password. The problem is, doing this client side is a really bad idea.

The alternative is to implement your own method to just pass email and password to check it.

or you can create your own API module to login customer

[android magento - customer login(authentication) using SOAP API](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72901/android-magento-customer-loginauthentication-using-soap-api)